# Connecting to AWS CloudFront: Secure Connection Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-cloudfront

Firefox https://static.allfile.net/lib/main.js :

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to static.allfile.net. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

```
$ curl -v https://static.allfile.net/lib/main.js
*   Trying 13.226.2.2:443...
* Connected to static.allfile.net (13.226.2.2) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
```

Why? It worked yesterday.

I have *TLSv1.2_2021 (recommended)* in CloudFront settings. I also have:
[x] HTTP/2
[ ] HTTP/3

"Legacy clients support - $600/month prorated charge applies. Most customers do not need this." is off.

Comment: When viewing with another computer (I have Ubuntu, the other one is Windows), there is no this problem.